# Inserting object into hash table... won't let me for some reason?

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm designing a simple program that takes an object of the Symbol class which I have defined and inserts into a HashTable. I've been given the HashTable.h file which came from our textbook and as you'll see, it is designed to be able to handle any object.

I'm trying to insert my object via:

```
hashtable.insert(&temp) //where temp is the object
```

However, I'm getting these errors:

```
    Driver.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    Driver.cpp:127:27: error: no matching function for call to 'HashTable<Symbol>::insert(Symbol*)'
    Driver.cpp:127:27: note: candidates are:
    In file included from Driver.cpp:12:0:
    SeperateChaining.h:50:10: note: bool HashTable<HashedObj>::insert(HashedObj&) [with HashedObj = Symbol]
    SeperateChaining.h:50:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Symbol*' to 'Symbol&'
    SeperateChaining.h:72:10: note: bool HashTable<HashedObj>::insert(HashedObj&&) [with HashedObj = Symbol]
    SeperateChaining.h:72:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Symbol*' to 'Symbol&&'
```

Would you guys mind taking a look?

EDIT: When I try to insert by value as many of you suggested, I get back a ton of garbage but parsed out for errors there are two:

```
opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:135:7: error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<Symbol>() == __val'
```

and

```
opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:135:7: error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<Symbol>() == __val' –
```

Here's my driver file and hash table.h file:

Driver.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cassert>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <map>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cmath>
    #include "SeperateChaining.h"

    //#include "hash_chn.h"

    using namespace std;

    int TABLE_SIZE; //I know it's a global, but it allows the Table Size to be taken in within main() and used in hash()

    size_t hash(const string & key);

    class Symbol
    {
    private:
        int key;
        int type;
        string data;
    public:
        const string & getData() const
        {
            return data;
        }
        int getType() 
        {
            return type;
        }
        int getKey()
        {
            return labs(key);
        }
        void setType(int Type)
        {   
            type = Type;
        }
        void setData(string Data)
        {
            data = Data;
        }
        void setKey(int Key)
        {
            key = Key;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        HashTable<Symbol> hashtable(TABLE_SIZE);
        Symbol temp;
        vector<Symbol> symbols;
        string s;
        int t;
        int hash_key_array[TABLE_SIZE]; //array to hold hash key values

        ifstream file;
        file.open("symbols.txt");

        if(!file)
        {
            cout << "System failed to open file.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "File successfully opened" << endl;
        }

        //for loop to read in the string name and the integer that follows the string name from symbols.txt
        while(file >> s)
        {
            temp.setData(s);
            file >> t;
            temp.setType(t);
            symbols.push_back(temp);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < symbols.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << symbols[i].getData() << "\n";
            cout << symbols[i].getType() << "\n";
        }

        cout << "What would you like the table size to be?" << endl;
        cout << "Note: If the table size is greater than the number of objects" <<
        " in the symbols.txt file, it will inevitably throw a segmentation fault" << endl;
        cin >> TABLE_SIZE;

        for(int j = 0; j < TABLE_SIZE; j++)
        {
            temp.setData(symbols[j].getData());
            cout << temp.getData() << endl;

            temp.setType(symbols[j].getType());
            cout << temp.getType() << endl;

            temp.setKey(::hash(symbols[j].getData()));
            cout << "The key is: " << temp.getKey() << endl;

            cout << endl;

            hash_key_array[j] = temp.getKey();


            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
            {
                if (i != j)
                {
                    if (hash_key_array[i] == hash_key_array[j])
                    {
                        cout << endl;
                        cout << "Collision occurred at " << hash_key_array[i] << endl;
                        //rehash();
                        //cout << "The new key is: " << temp.getKey() << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        hashtable.insert(&temp); //problem is here


        }
    }

    size_t hash(const string & key)
    {
        size_t hashVal = 0;

        for(char ch : key)
        {
            hashVal = 37 * hashVal + ch;
        }
        return labs(hashVal);
    }
```

SeperateChaining.h:

```
#ifndef SEPARATE_CHAINING_H
#define SEPARATE_CHAINING_H

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
//#include "Hash.h"
using namespace std;

// SeparateChaining Hash table class
//
// CONSTRUCTION: an approximate initial size or default of 101
//
// ******************PUBLIC OPERATIONS*********************
// bool insert( x )       --> Insert x
// bool remove( x )       --> Remove x
// bool contains( x )     --> Return true if x is present
// void makeEmpty( )      --> Remove all items

template <typename HashedObj>
class HashTable
{
  public:

    //Uses the whatever value table_size has
    //Otherwise, it will make a hash table of size 101
    explicit HashTable( int TABLE_SIZE )
    { 
        currentSize = 0;
        theLists.resize(TABLE_SIZE); 
    }

    bool contains( const HashedObj & x ) const
    {
        //represents the correct list in the hash table vector to start looking through
        auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( x ) ];

        //returns whatever you wanted to search for in the table provided it is there
        return find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), x ) != end( whichList );
    }

    void makeEmpty( )
    {
        for( auto & thisList : theLists )
            thisList.clear( );
    }

    bool insert(HashedObj & temp )
    {
         //represents the correct list in the hash table vector to start looking through
        auto & whichList = theLists[myhash( temp )];

        //goes through the beginning and end of the list, and if it
        //doesn't get to the end, then it found the object you wanted to insert in the hash table already
        //prevents duplicate insertions
        if( find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), temp ) != end( whichList) )
            return false;

        //otherwise, it has gotten to the end of the list without finding a duplicate
        //and puts what you want to insert in the list
        whichList.push_back( temp );

        // Rehash; see Section 5.5
        if( ++currentSize > theLists.size( ) )
            rehash( );

        return true;
    }

    bool insert( HashedObj && x )
    {
        auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( x ) ];      
        if( find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), x ) != end( whichList ) )
            return false;
        whichList.push_back( std::move( x ) );

            // Rehash; see Section 5.5
        if( ++currentSize > theLists.size( ) )
            rehash( );

        return true;
    }

    bool remove( const HashedObj & x )
    {
        //represents the correct list in the hash table vector to start looking through
        auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( x ) ];

        //trying to find x within the list
        //the iterator points to the slot in the list that contains x
        auto itr = find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), x );

        //if it gets to the end of the list without finding what you want to remove, then it returns false
        if( itr == end( whichList ) )
        {
            return false;
        }


        //if it finds x, it removes it from the list
        whichList.erase( itr );
        --currentSize;
        return true;
    }

    /*
    void printTable()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < symbols.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "The hash table contains: " << symbols[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    */

  private: 
     vector<list<HashedObj>> theLists;   // The array of Lists
     int  currentSize;

     void rehash( )
     {
         vector<list<HashedObj>> oldLists = theLists;

         // Creates new double-sized, empty table
         theLists.resize( nextPrime( 2 * theLists.size( ) ) );
         for( auto & thisList : theLists )
             thisList.clear( );

         // Copies the old table into the new table
         currentSize = 0;
         for( auto & thisList : oldLists )
             for( auto & x : thisList )
                 insert( std::move( x ) );
     }

     size_t myhash( const HashedObj & x ) const
     {
         static hash<HashedObj> hf;
         return hf( x ) % theLists.size( );
        }
  };

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

> hashtable.insert(&temp)

You have to insert by value, not by pointer. Remove the & operator.

Comment: I tried that but I get pages long worth of errors and I have no idea why

Comment: @user2704533 Well I'm afraid you'll have to understand the error messages instead of trying blindly. Focus on the first error you get and ignore the rest, that are most likely just follow-up errors!

Comment: After parsing through the 6 pages worth of stuff it threw back it me I got the following errors: /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/functional_hash.h:60:7: error: static assertion failed: std::hash is not specialized for this type                                                     and opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:135:7: error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<Symbol>() == __val'

Comment: Does your textbook tell you that you need to provide a `std::hash` specialization for your class? No offense, but this is pretty advanced C++ stuff... Maybe you should try something simpler first?

Answer (score 0):

```
hashtable.insert(&temp);
                 ^
```

You are trying to insert an address of temp. This is what this error says:

> note: bool HashTable::insert(HashedObj&) [with HashedObj =
>
> Symbol] note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Symbol*' to
>   'Symbol&'

There is a version of `insert` that takes a reference as its argument. So instead of pointer insert the object by value:

```
hashtable.insert(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the errors you are getting:

```
SeperateChaining.h:50:10: note: bool HashTable<HashedObj>::insert(HashedObj&) [with HashedObj = Symbol]
SeperateChaining.h:50:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Symbol*' to 'Symbol&'
SeperateChaining.h:72:10: note: bool HashTable<HashedObj>::insert(HashedObj&&) [with HashedObj = Symbol]
SeperateChaining.h:72:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Symbol*' to 'Symbol&&'
```

This is telling you that you are calling `insert` with a `Symbol*` and the function `insert` takes either a `Symbol&` or a `Symbol&&`.

So, let's look at the code where you call `insert`:

```
hashtable.insert(&temp); //problem is here
```

Sure enough, you are using `&` which is the `address-of operator` which will take the address of `temp`, which is of type `Symbol`, returning a pointer to it (which is, of course, of type `Symbol*`). So you're calling the function with `Symbol*`, which is not what the functions expect.

Sidenote: your implementation has a few other issues that you will need to sort through. Ask yourself what is `temp` and what does the `HashTable` class do with the l- and r-value references to `Symbol` that it accepts?